# Не обновляються данные в базе

Tags: php, mysql

Ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near
> '3,`author`=Автор 3,;
> .=`genre`=Детская
> литература,`about`=drghdzhdh,`price'at
> line1

edit_book.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Редактировать книгу</title>
</head>
<?
include('../config.php');

if (!isset($id))
{
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM catalog");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0){
    echo "Не найдено ни одной записи";
} else {
    print("<form method=\"post\">");
                    print("<table border=\"2\" align=\"center\">");
                    print("<tr>");
                    print("<td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Genre</td><td>About</td><td>Price</td><td>About_all</td>");
                    print("<td>Delete</td>");
                    print("<td>Update</td>");
                    print("</tr>");
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        print ("<tr>");
                        $aName1 = $row['name'];
                        $aName2 = $row['author'];
                        $aName3 = $row['genre'];
                        $aName4 = $row['about'];
                        $aName5 = $row['price'];
                        $aName6 = $row['id'];
                        $aName7 = $row['about_all'];
                        print("<td>$aName1</td>");
                                                print("<td>$aName2</td>");
                                                print("<td>$aName3</td>");
                        print("<td>$aName4</td>");
                        print("<td>$aName5</td>");
                        print("<td>$aName7</td>");
                        print("<td>");
                        print("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete[]\" value=\"$aName6\">");  
                        print("</td>");
                        print("<td>");
                        print("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"update[]\" value=\"$aName6\">");  
                        print("</td>");
                        print("</tr>");
                                }
                            print("</table>");
                            print("<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value=\"Delete\">");
                            print("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Update\" value=\"Select Update\"></div>");
                            print("</form>");
                    }
}
class DataBase {
    function UpdateRecord($aName1,$aName2,$aName3,$aName4,$aName5,$aName6){
        $aSQL="update catalog set `name`=$aName1,`author`=$aName2,;
        $aSQL.=`genre`=$aName3,`about`=$aName4,`price`=$aName5,`about_all` = $aName6 where `id`=$aName7";
                $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                    echo "Update OK!";
                } else {echo mysql_error();}//print("ERROR Update Record!<br>.mysql_error()");}

                                }

function DeleteRecord($aNomer){
    $aDBLink=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!empty($aDBLink)){
        if(mysql_select_db("catalog",$aDBLink)==True){
            $aSQL="delete from `catalog` where `id`=".$aNomer;
            $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL,$aDBLink);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                        } else { echo mysql_error();}

                }}
                    }
 function SelectUpdateRecord(){
            $aSQL="select * from catalog where id=";
            $aCOUNT=count($_POST['update']);
            $aNEXT=0;
            foreach($_POST['update'] as $val){
                $aSQL.="$val";
                $aNEXT++;
                if($aNEXT<$aCOUNT){
                $aSQL.=" or id=";
                          }
                              }
                $aDBLink=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!empty($aDBLink)){
                if(mysql_select_db("catalog",$aDBLink)==True){
                $aQResult=mysql_query($aSQL,$aDBLink);
                if($aQResult==TRUE){
                            print("<form method=\"post\">");
                            print("<table border=\"2\" align=\"center\">");
                            print("<tr>");
                            print("<td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Genre</td><td>About</td><td>Price</td>");
                            print("<td>About_all</td>");
                            print("<td>Id</td>");
                            print("</tr>");

    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($aQResult);
    while($aRow=mysql_fetch_array($aQResult)){
                            $aName1=$aRow["name"];
                            $aName2=$aRow["author"];
                            $aName3=$aRow["genre"];
                            $aName4=$aRow["about"];
                            $aName5=$aRow["price"];
                            $aName6=$aRow["about_all"];
                            $aName7=$aRow["id"];
                            print("<tr>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name[]\" value=\"$aName1\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"author[]\" value=\"$aName2\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"genre[]\" value=\"$aName3\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"about[]\" value=\"$aName4\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"price[]\" value=\"$aName5\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"about_all[]\" value=\"$aName6\"></td>");
                            print("<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id[]\" value=\"$aName7\"></td>");
                            print("</tr>");
                        }
                            print("</table>");
                            print("<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"OkUpdate\" value=\"Update Ok!\"></div>");
                            print("</form>");
                            }
                                        }
                     }
                    }

}

$data=new DataBase();
if(isset($_POST['Delete']) && $_POST['Delete']){
                                    if($_POST['delete']){
                                        foreach($_POST['delete'] as $val){
                                        $data->DeleteRecord($val);
                                                                                }
                            }

                        }
                if(isset($_POST['Update']) && $_POST['Update']){
if($_POST['update']){
        $data->SelectUpdateRecord();
            }
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['OkUpdate']) && $_POST['OkUpdate']){
                    $aS1=0;

foreach($_POST['name'] as $val1){
                    $Name1[]=$val1;
                    $aS1++;
                }
    foreach($_POST['author'] as $val2){
                    $Name2[]=$val2;
                }
    foreach($_POST['genre'] as $val3){
                    $Name3[]=$val3;
                }
    foreach($_POST['about'] as $val4){
                    $Name4[]=$val4;
                }
    foreach($_POST['price'] as $val5){
                    $Name5[]=$val5;
                }
    foreach($_POST['about_all'] as $val6){
                    $Name6[]=$val6;
                }
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $val7){
                    $Name7[]=$val7;
                }

    for($count=0;$count<$aS1;$count++){
       $data->UpdateRecord($Name1[$count],$Name2[$count],$Name3[$count],$Name4[$count],$Name5[$    count],$Name6[$count],$Name7[$count]);
                }
                    }
    ?>
    <div align="center"><a href="admin.php">Назад в админ-панель</a><br></div>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Лютый ппц. Неужели так тяжело разметить код как код? Кнопочка специальная для этого есть, с нулями и единицами.

Comment: Заодно и лютый программизд, выводящий html-элементы print'ом :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экранируйте имена столбцов символом **`** , а их значения одинарными кавычками.

Пример:

...`author`='Автор 3', `genre`='Детская литература', `about`='drghdzhdh'...

Answer (score 2):

Не надо делать запрос интерполируемой строкой и совать прямо в него переменные!

Читайте про [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) до полного просветления.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в синтаксисе. Где то ковычку или запятую пропустил в **запросе**. Больше ничего сказать не могу, раскуривать код не буду.